# Project Euler 8 types and casting

Tags: c++

The question is to find the thirteen adjacent digits in the 1000-digit number that have the greatest product and the value of this product. This is the number:

73167176531330624919225119674426574742355349194934
96983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843
85861560789112949495459501737958331952853208805511
12540698747158523863050715693290963295227443043557
66896648950445244523161731856403098711121722383113
62229893423380308135336276614282806444486645238749
30358907296290491560440772390713810515859307960866
70172427121883998797908792274921901699720888093776
65727333001053367881220235421809751254540594752243
52584907711670556013604839586446706324415722155397
53697817977846174064955149290862569321978468622482
83972241375657056057490261407972968652414535100474
82166370484403199890008895243450658541227588666881
16427171479924442928230863465674813919123162824586
17866458359124566529476545682848912883142607690042
24219022671055626321111109370544217506941658960408
07198403850962455444362981230987879927244284909188
84580156166097919133875499200524063689912560717606
05886116467109405077541002256983155200055935729725
71636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450

I've done it like that:

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
string num = /*the number*/
unsigned long int x;
unsigned long int r = 0;
unsigned long int b;

for (int i = 0; i < num.length() -12; i++){
    x = ((unsigned long int)num[i]);
    x %= 48;
    for (int j = i+1; j < i+13; j++){
            b = ((unsigned long int)num[j] % 48);
            x *= b;

    }
    if (r < x)
        r = x;
}
cout << r;
system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

but i keep getting wrong answers. I think there is an issue with types and casting because every time I change them (eq. long) i get different answers.

Comment: why `x %=48` ? What is this `48` in your code?

Comment: @tobi303 It is a confusing way to perform `x = x - '0'`, i.e. get the digit's value.

Comment: it is changing ASCII number to digits, eq. 7 has ASCII '55' so 55%48 is 7.

Comment: Try to use `long long` everywhere. If `long` is 32 bits on your platform then the product of 13 digits might overflow.

Comment: Is it related to this question? [Project Euler #8, I don't understand where I'm going wrong](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23824570/project-euler-8-i-dont-understand-where-im-going-wrong)

Comment: if overflow is the problem (9^13 is a quite large number) you could do the product with doubles and dividing each number by 5 before. In this way half numbers are above 1 and the other half below one and the product doesnt grow so extreme, but the final result will be the same.

Comment: I mean the minimum will be at the same position, if you then need the value of the product just multiply the value (the one from the values*0.2) with 5^13.

Comment: I did change to long long, but answer is still wrong. Yeah I saw this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23824570/project-euler-8-i-dont-understand-where-im-going-wrong did what he did but didn't help :(

Comment: @tobi303 `unsigned long long`  can more than handle 9^13. 9^13 is 2,541,865,828,329 where `unsigned long long` can hold 18,446,744,073,709,551,615

Comment: @NathanOliver hmm, right. Still I would try it just for the fun of it ;)

Comment: Changed to `unsigned long long` its working :) thanks!

Comment: @Cardano What did you change to `unsigned long long `? `x`, `r` and `b` are already `unsigned long long` in the code you posted.

Comment: They are `unsigned long` if this changes anything, I hope i didn't just made a mistake copying solution to the site :/

Comment: @Cardano - The sizes of `long` and `long long` might, or might not, both be 64-bit. It varies with compiler and operating system (which we don't know). Or wait, you use `_tmain` which is Windows only. There `long` is 32-bit.