# Project Euler Q8 Largest product in a series - Why is my code wrong?

Tags: f#

The problem is ([source](https://projecteuler.net/problem=8))...

> The four adjacent digits in the 1000-digit number that have the greatest
>   product are 9 × 9 × 8 × 9 = 5832.
>
> 73167176531330624919225119674426574742355349194934
>   96983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843
>   85861560789112949495459501737958331952853208805511
>   12540698747158523863050715693290963295227443043557
>   66896648950445244523161731856403098711121722383113
>   62229893423380308135336276614282806444486645238749
>   30358907296290491560440772390713810515859307960866
>   70172427121883998797908792274921901699720888093776
>   65727333001053367881220235421809751254540594752243
>   52584907711670556013604839586446706324415722155397
>   53697817977846174064955149290862569321978468622482
>   83972241375657056057490261407972968652414535100474
>   82166370484403199890008895243450658541227588666881
>   16427171479924442928230863465674813919123162824586
>   17866458359124566529476545682848912883142607690042
>   24219022671055626321111109370544217506941658960408
>   07198403850962455444362981230987879927244284909188
>   84580156166097919133875499200524063689912560717606
>   05886116467109405077541002256983155200055935729725
>   71636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450
>
> Find the thirteen adjacent digits in the 1000-digit number that have
>   the greatest product. What is the value of this product?

I have the following F#...

```
let largestProduct n (s : string) =
  [ for i in [0..(s.Length - n)] do yield s.[i..(i + n - 1)]]
  |> Seq.map (fun s -> s, s |> Seq.fold (fun p c -> p * (int (string c))) 1)
  |> Seq.maxBy snd
```

You pass the number of digits, and the 1000 digit number as a string. The first line produces a sequence of n-character strings, which are piped into the second line where the product of the digits is calculated. This is wrapped in a tuple with the n-character string, so I can see which set of n characters produced the highest product. The last line gets the maximum product.

If I run this as follows...

```
largestProduct 4 nStr
```

...where nStr is the 1000-digit number as a string, it produces the following...

```
("9989", 5832)
```

...which is correct. However, if I change the number to 13, to solve the actual problem, it gives me...

```
("9781797784617", 2091059712)
```

...which apparently is wrong.

Anyone any idea why my code doesn't work? I've tried it for various small values of n, and it looks like it's working there. I've also tried it on shorter strings, and it seems to work fine.

Comment: The maximum value that can be stored in an `int` without overflowing is `2147483647`.  While your particular substring doesn't cause overflow, probably the correct substring does.  Try using an `int64` instead, which can store 9^13, so is safe.

Comment: @kvb Thanks, I just discovered the same thing and was coming back to post an answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This exercise causes an Int32 to overflow. The arbitrary-length type `bigint` solves this for a generally sufficient range of inputs. For example:

```
let digitsToProduct inp =
    inp |> Seq.map (string >> bigint.Parse)
        |> Seq.fold (*) 1I

let largestProduct n : (seq<char> -> bigint) =
    Seq.windowed n >> Seq.map digitsToProduct >> Seq.max
```

*Edit: note that `largestProduct` takes a second argument: a string (or any char sequence) of the 1000 digits.*

### What can be learned from this?

This is a fundamental kind of problem that is worth thinking about. As a rule of thumb, a function should be correct or fail, at least for reasonable inputs. I would argue that, in any context where a developer might make such mistakes, the answer to just use a 64-bit integer is borderline incorrect. After all, it will still fail silently on inputs that are too large.

If you want to use a 32-bit or 64-bit integer for such a function, **validate your inputs!**

For example, a rough validation could be:

```
// 32b version
if n > 9 then invalidArg "n" "number of digits too large for Int32."
// 64b version
if n > 19L then invalidArg "n" "number of digits too large for Int64."
```

This would cause your program to *fail properly* instead of silently producing nonsensical results.

Comment: I wish I could give you more than one vote! Your answer was spot on for several reasons. First it introduced me to Seq.windowed which I'd never seen before (still relatively new to F#), and second, your comments about thinking about the domain are absolutely right. As I happens, the same thought occurred to me later on after posting my answer, and I think the whole exercise was more valuable for that lesson than for the F# I wrote!

Comment: Looking again, I can't see how your code works. Where do you pass the 1000 digit number in? Also, can you explain how the last line works? Thanks

Comment: @AvrohomYisroel Call `largestProduct 13 inputDigits`, where `inputDigits` is a string (or other char sequence) containing only the 1000 digits (no spaces/newlines). The last line is a chain of three functions: first: build sliding windows of n characters from the input sequence, second: calculate the product of digits for each of them, third: get the maximum of these products. Maybe it's a bad habit that I used function composition and thereby made the second argument of `largestProduct` implicit.

Comment: I tried calling it like that, but got an error "The type 'string' is not compatible with the type 'seq<obj>'" when I passed the 1000 digit number as a string. Also, can you explain what you meant by the last sentence. I'm still puzzled how you didn't need to include the string as a parameter when you declared the function. Thx

Comment: @AvrohomYisroel Oh, I see your problem now. I had all code in a single FSX file, so type inference figured out the type. I added a type annotation to my answer that should prevent the problem. (Alternatively, mark both functions `inline`.) The reason I didn't need to include the string as a parameter is that the function returns a function, which then takes the next parameter. Note that I'm using the `>>` operator for function composition; the result expression of the last line is itself a function that still takes the sequence of digits as input.

Answer (score 4):

As you've figured, using `int64` solves the problem.

The way I read the assignment, you don't have to return the digits that cause the largest product; only the product itself is required. With that requirement, the implementation is easy:

```
let largestProduct n : (string -> int64) =
    Seq.map (string >> System.Int64.Parse)
    >> Seq.windowed n
    >> Seq.map (Array.fold (*) 1L)
    >> Seq.max
```

If you want the sequence of digits as well, that's also easy:

```
let largestProductAndTheDigitsThatProduceIt n : (string -> string * int64) =
    Seq.map (string >> System.Int64.Parse)
    >> Seq.windowed n
    >> Seq.map (fun is -> System.String.Concat is , Array.fold (*) 1L is)
    >> Seq.maxBy snd
```

FSI:

```
> largestProductAndTheDigitsThatProduceIt 4 nStr;;
val it : string * int64 = ("9989", 5832L)
> largestProductAndTheDigitsThatProduceIt 13 nStr;;
val it : string * int64 = ("5576689664895", 23514624000L)
```

Comment: I added the digits that caused the largest product for my own purposes, and left them in the final code as they didn't do any harm. Thanks for your reply, which introduced me to Seq.windowed (along with Vandroiy's answer). I'm still learning F#, and finding this fascinating.

Answer (score 3):

Whilst searching for some inspiration, I came across a question where [someone had the same problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23824570/project-euler-8-i-dont-understand-where-im-going-wrong).

The answer was nothing more complex than the fact that the multiplication overflowed the capacity of a 32-bit integer. When I altered the code to use int64, it gave the right answer...

```
let largestProductInt64 (n : int64) (s : string) =
  [ for i in [0L..((int64 s.Length) - n)] do yield s.[(int i)..int(i + n - 1L)]]
  |> Seq.map (fun s -> s, s |> Seq.fold (fun p c -> p * (int64 (int (string c)))) 1L)
  |> Seq.maxBy snd
```

Shame, as the code isn't as neat and clean, but it works.

Thanks to @kvb who made the same point in a comment before I had chance to post my own findings.