# The Euler website 8th work

Tags: c++, for-loop, long-integer

This is my approach to the Euler website 8th problem. I know that because of its intricated loops is not minimal. But, I would like to know why it works for small numbers and not works for big ones. Say, for the number wanted in the Euler problem, it returns `8502282159491788800` that is a false answer. My guess is that the problem is an incorrect usage of 'long long' type. How can I repair this code?

`the Euler website 8th problem:`

**Find the thirteen adjacent digits in the 1000-digit number that have the greatest product. What is the value of this product?**

`My code:`

```
  // Euler website 8th problem.
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

bool alter(long long  a, long long b) {
  // returns true when two numbers differe in 1.
  bool _default = true;
  if (a != b + 1 and a != b - 1) {
  _default = false;
    }
  return _default;
  }

long long prod(long long a, long long b) {
  // computes \( a * \cdots * b \) or \( b * \cdots * a \).
  if (a > b) {
    long long  cng = a;
    a = b;
    b = cng;
    }
  long long _tmp = 1;
  for (long long i = a; i <= b; i++) {
    _tmp = _tmp * i;
    }
    return _tmp;
  }


int main () {
  std::string num = "7316717653133062491922511967442657474235534919493496983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843858615607891129494954595017379583319528532088055111254069874715852386305071569329096329522744304355766896648950445244523161731856403098711121722383113622298934233803081353362766142828064444866452387493035890729629049156044077239071381051585930796086670172427121883998797908792274921901699720888093776657273330010533678812202354218097512545405947522435258490771167055601360483958644670632441572215539753697817977846174064955149290862569321978468622482839722413756570560574902614079729686524145351004748216637048440319989000889524345065854122758866688116427171479924442928230863465674813919123162824586178664583591245665294765456828489128831426076900422421902267105562632111110937054421750694165896040807198403850962455444362981230987879927244284909188845801561660979191338754992005240636899125607176060588611646710940507754100225698315520005593572972571636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450";
  long long _n = 13;
  long long _result = 0;
  for (long long i = 0; i < (long long) num.length() - _n + 1; i++) {
    for (long long j = i; j < i + _n - 1; j++) {
      if (alter(num.at(j), num.at(j + 1))) {
        _result = prod(j, j + _n - 1);
      }
    }
  }
  std::cout << _result << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: And what is the correct answer?

Comment: try to find their product modulo some number, let's say 10^9. and see if it looks like last 9 digits of the right answer.

Comment: @MichaelWalz Dear Michael I dont know the right answer. But when I give my answer to the Euler website they said me it is not true.

Comment: When you say "adjacent digits", do you mean digits that differ by one, or digits that are next to one another in the original number?

Comment: I don't see how your code multiplies adjacent digits, and it produces zero for the trivial input `"1111111111111"` (and for any sequence of `1`s, for that matter).

Comment: This code looks pretty complex.  Don't all you need to do is take a rolling 13 character piece of the string and see if all the digits have the highest product?

Comment: You probably misunderstood the problem. You are trying to multiply digits that differ by 1, but the problem states that you should multiply adjacent digits, that is digits that are next to each other.

Comment: Try checking out [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23824570/10077) on the same problem.

Comment: Here's some test data. In the number 123450 there are three possible products of 4 asjacent digits, `1*2*3*4=24` `2*3*4*5=120` and `3*4*5*0=0`, the second one being the greatest among them. Does your program produce the correct answer?

Comment: @FredLarson Dear Fred I saw this question before asking here. I would like to solve my problem on my own code.

Comment: @molbdnilo It will return 0 as my plan.  But why? Thanks to the boolean alter function, it bahaves to produce 0 (because 1111111111111 has no alter digits) and it is welcomed to me.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp I mean digits that are differ by 1 exactly.

Comment: @MichaelWalz This condition: a != b + 1 and a != b - 1 in the boolean alter function, shows that I consider adjacent numbers.

Comment: @NathanOliver Yes. I implement just this plan by my approach. As I said before, this is not the optimal code. But, my question is that where is my mistake in the algorithm. Why it fails for some numbers and why it produce the correct result for some another numbers? Where is my mistake?

Comment: @n.m. No. Indeed, putting _num = "123450"  and  _n = 4, it returns 360 as an incorrect answer. But, with the same _num = "123450"  with  _n = 3, it returns 60 as the correct answer. Thanks for your nice counterexample, now I know that my algorithm has some bugs. But, I can not debug it.

Comment: @Baghban We are saying that you are incorrect in your assumption about what "adjacent" means. I believe they mean "next to one another". For example in "98246800", 2,4,6, and 8 are adjacent because they are next to one another in the string.

Comment: @Baghban could you explain how "123450" and n=4 returns 360? What steps are taken exactly?

Comment: @JohnnyMopp Based on their default example; namely 
The four adjacent digits in the 1000-digit number that have the greatest product are 9 × 9 × 8 × 9 = 5832.
at https://projecteuler.net/problem=8 I think that their mean of "adjacent" is "differ by one".

Comment: @MichaelWalz  For this case, it is sufficient to put in the code: num = "123450" and _n = 4 in the code. The correct answer should be 120 in this case. But the code returns 360.

Comment: @Baghban I believe that is just a coincidence. What would the solution be for "2468024680"? There are no digits that differ by one.

Comment: "But the code returns 360." No wonder, it never ever tries to get digits from the number and multiply them.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp It returns 0, as my plan (= my assumption about the meaning of adjecant).

Comment: Ok. That's up to you. I just did a quick search for Project Euler 8 Solutions and they all used my definition of "adjacent" - next to one another in the string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to fix the definition of **adjacent** as the same as mentioned by @Johnny Mopp. So, in your first function, you must modify the if-condition as just `a < b`. Now, on the second function you need to do some fundamental changes. Indeed, you SHOULD do a multiplication of digits, and not a multiplication of all integers between any pair of them. This mistake is done in the main body by `alter(num.at(j), num.at(j + 1))`. So, in my opinion this could be a suitable code for your second function:

```
long long prod(std::string _str) {
  if (_str.find('0') != std::string::npos) {
    return 0;
    }
  else {
      long long _number = std::stoll(_str);
  long long _tmp, _prod = 1;
  while(_number > 0) {
    _tmp = _number % 10; 
    _prod *= _tmp;
    _number = _number / 10;
    }
    return _prod;
    }
  }
```

And, finally the if-statement in the main body:

```
      if (alter(num.at(j), num.at(j + 1)) and prod(num.substr(j, _n)) > _result) {
        _result = prod(num.substr(j, _n));
      }
```