# Project Euler Problem 8 Python integer overflow

Tags: python, integer-overflow

The problem asks you to "Find the thirteen adjacent digits in the 1000-digit number that have the greatest product." for the following number:

7316717653133062491922511967442657474235534919493496983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843858615607891129494954595017379583319528532088055111254069874715852386305071569329096329522744304355766896648950445244523161731856403098711121722383113622298934233803081353362766142828064444866452387493035890729629049156044077239071381051585930796086670172427121883998797908792274921901699720888093776657273330010533678812202354218097512545405947522435258490771167055601360483958644670632441572215539753697817977846174064955149290862569321978468622482839722413756570560574902614079729686524145351004748216637048440319989000889524345065854122758866688116427171479924442928230863465674813919123162824586178664583591245665294765456828489128831426076900422421902267105562632111110937054421750694165896040807198403850962455444362981230987879927244284909188845801561660979191338754992005240636899125607176060588611646710940507754100225698315520005593572972571636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450

My code in Python is as follows (which I am sure isn't the most efficient):

```
import numpy

a= "7316717653133062491922511967442657474235534919493496983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843858615607891129494954595017379583319528532088055111254069874715852386305071569329096329522744304355766896648950445244523161731856403098711121722383113622298934233803081353362766142828064444866452387493035890729629049156044077239071381051585930796086670172427121883998797908792274921901699720888093776657273330010533678812202354218097512545405947522435258490771167055601360483958644670632441572215539753697817977846174064955149290862569321978468622482839722413756570560574902614079729686524145351004748216637048440319989000889524345065854122758866688116427171479924442928230863465674813919123162824586178664583591245665294765456828489128831426076900422421902267105562632111110937054421750694165896040807198403850962455444362981230987879927244284909188845801561660979191338754992005240636899125607176060588611646710940507754100225698315520005593572972571636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450"

res=0       #the product we want to be returned
reslst=[]    #the list of the elements in the product
i = 0
while i<988:
    ilst=[int(a[j]) for j in range(i,i+13)]
    if numpy.prod(ilst)>res:
        res = (numpy.prod(ilst))
        reslst = ilst
        i +=1
    else:
        i +=1
print(res,reslst)
```

However as in the following post regarding this problem in c++:

[Project Euler #8, I don't understand where I'm going wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23824570/project-euler-8-i-dont-understand-where-im-going-wrong)
I get the wrong answer 2091059712 [9, 7, 8, 1, 7, 9, 7, 7, 8, 4, 6, 1, 7]

But everywhere I looked online suggests integer overflows and longs and signed integers, with which I am not familiar, as I only have limited experience, and of Python. Googling seems to say that integer overflow should not be a problem in python.

I'm sure there is something elementary I must not know about Python, so thank you in advance for teaching me this.

Comment: As you are using `numpy`, the data types being used are one of the following: https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/basics.types.html. Basically, what you are seeing is what you would see if you were using `C`. You need to remove `numpy` and calculate your product manually in base Python.

Comment: Ah I see, thanks! Does that also mean perhaps, as in the C case where people said to use long long, one could somehow use np.longlong to get around this? In any case I'll calculate the product manually now.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
ilst=np.array([int(a[j]) for j in range(i,i+13)],dtype=np.longlong)
```

I then get 23514624000 [5 5 7 6 6 8 9 6 6 4 8 9 5]

Answer (score 0):

The key is to represent the number as a string. You code worked correctly for me:

```
import numpy
a = '7316717653133062491922511967442657474235534919493496983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843858615607891129494954595017379583319528532088055111254069874715852386305071569329096329522744304355766896648950445244523161731856403098711121722383113622298934233803081353362766142828064444866452387493035890729629049156044077239071381051585930796086670172427121883998797908792274921901699720888093776657273330010533678812202354218097512545405947522435258490771167055601360483958644670632441572215539753697817977846174064955149290862569321978468622482839722413756570560574902614079729686524145351004748216637048440319989000889524345065854122758866688116427171479924442928230863465674813919123162824586178664583591245665294765456828489128831426076900422421902267105562632111110937054421750694165896040807198403850962455444362981230987879927244284909188845801561660979191338754992005240636899125607176060588611646710940507754100225698315520005593572972571636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450'
res=0       #the product we want to be returned
reslst=[]    #the list of the elements in the product
i = 0
while i<988:
    ilst=[int(a[j]) for j in range(i,i+13)]
    if numpy.prod(ilst)>res:
        res = (numpy.prod(ilst))
        reslst = ilst
        i +=1
    else:
        i +=1
>>> print(res,reslst)

23514624000 [5, 5, 7, 6, 6, 8, 9, 6, 6, 4, 8, 9, 5]
```

Comment: For me it doesn't. I still get `2091059712 [9, 7, 8, 1, 7, 9, 7, 7, 8, 4, 6, 1, 7]` with `platform.python_version() 3.8.3rc1` and `numpy.__version__ 1.18.4`

Comment: Yes, for me too. Sorry, Sam I've just realised I had inputted the number as a string but in trying not to have to type it out again here, I forgot to show that. I've edited my code on here now., which gives the wrong answer.

Comment: Strange, I just copied your code and got the correct answer. The versions I'm using are: `python 3.7.2`, `numpy 1.16.3`