# Finding the largest n-digit product in a sequence of numbers

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy

The aim is to find the n-digit number within a range of numbers with length > n, with the highest product.
E.g., in the 1000 digit number below, find a sequence of thirteen digits where theire product is maximum.

```
import numpy as np
n = 13
# for visual readibility the number is truncated in this example
x = '''73167176531330624919225117...2483600823257530420752963450'''

#make a list of all possible thirteen adjacent digits with no 0    
y = [x[i:i+n] for i in range(len(x)) if '0' not in x[i:i+n] and i+n < len(x)]

#convert to int and multiply     
y3d = [np.array(list(y[i]), dtype=int) for i in range(len(y))]     
multiplied = [np.prod(y3d[i]) for i in range(len(y3d))]

print(max(multiplied))
```

numbers =

> > 7316717653133062491922511967442657474235534919493496983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843858615607891129494954595017379583319528532088055111254069874715852386305071569329096329522744304355766896648950445244523161731856403098711121722383113622298934233803081353362766142828064444866452387493035890729629049156044077239071381051585930796086670172427121883998797908792274921901699720888093776657273330010533678812202354218097512545405947522435258490771167055601360483958644670632441572215539753697817977846174064955149290862569321978468622482839722413756570560574902614079729686524145351004748216637048440319989000889524345065854122758866688116427171479924442928230863465674813919123162824586178664583591245665294765456828489128831426076900422421902267105562632111110937054421750694165896040807198403850962455444362981230987879927244284909188845801561660979191338754992005240636899125607176060588611646710940507754100225698315520005593572972571636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450

its work on 1 to 12 digits but im having a hard time on 13

Comment: trying to find the thirteen adjacent digits in the 1000-digit number that have the greatest product

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to SO @Gelar Anugerah.

I am not sure that your code works for 4 digits.

the issue is that the variable 'multy' is not defined and you should replace it with

```
    print(max(multiplied))
```

and then you should get the index of the `max` value and print the right sequence:

```
    j = multiplied.index(max(multiplied))
    print(y3d[j])
```

Comment: Yeah, I made a mistake in the multy variable, I should also change the 13 to variable n where n is the number of adjacent digits. I did it and it does works on 4 digits. I think I should find my solution here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23824570/project-euler-8-i-dont-understand-where-im-going-wrong because I also get the result 2091059712

Comment: in your last y3d print, you always print the last cell of the array, the updated response fixes that too.

Comment: The y3d print is just to check if the code create the list until the last possible combination(Should add comment for that). I think my problem happen because an Integer Overflow https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow. Because the right answer is above the overflow range